# How to get the construct of an existing elasticache cluster using AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-elasticache, aws-cdk-typescript

I have a AWS CDK app, which has a lambda function which needs to read from an existing elasticache redis cluster. The lambda needs the cluster's connection parameters as well as I have to provide permissions for the lambda to read from the redis db. I went through this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_elasticache.CfnCacheCluster.html

Generally most CDK constructs have a static method resembling something like `fromLookup` or `fromARN` to give access to an existing resource, but I couldn't find something similar for the `CfnCacheCluster` construct... Is it possible to get the elasticache cluster through some other route?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue!

Comment: Nope, we had a workaround. We exported SSM parameters necessary for connection and imported in the CDK project.